# Waiting for Server Response Before Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I'm doing a self development project using C# and asp.net. It's a card game and I'm writing a matchmaking system for it. How I would like for it to work is that you click the "Play Game" button and it takes you to a new page where you wait for another player to join, before it redirects you to the game page. So, ideally, you'd go to the wait page; the page is like "Hold on" and listens for the server; the server accepts another player for the game, and pings the first person saying "Alright, let's go" and takes both players to the game area.  My question is how do I get the client to wait for a server response like that before redirecting?

Comment: Down voters should include a comment as to why they're down voting. My assumption is that you should've also included what you've tried and why those attempts didn't work. I would suggest going through the tour since it explains everything: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I hadn't really tried much of anything, just mainly research and I was coming up empty-handed. Google really wanted me to look into the Monitor class, it seemed, and other questions on stack overflow more dealt with waiting for a period of time, or had answers that seemed a little more complex than what I was expecting (seemingly trying to get me to venture into a multithreaded solution), and I just figured there was a better way. What I had tried was a while loop on the post that locked up the server and I immediately thought "that was silly of me to even think that would work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple different methods that you can use.

You can poll between client and server using [javascript's setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout). The idea being that when the timeout occurs, you redirect to the matchmaking page (or similar) and if there is a match, then you can redirect them to join the game. If there isn't a match, the player gets redirected to the waiting screen where the setTimeout is set again.

A second method to use is [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). This is an HTML5 standard which allows for direct communication between a client and a server. The problem here is that you would need to enforce the clients to be a modern browser to use HTML5.

<strike>Microsoft has a specific library out there that deals with this situation without polling and as soon as my brain kicks in again, I'll update my post with it.</strike>

Since you're using C#, you can also use [SignalR](http://signalr.net/). SignalR is a library which allows your server to communicate in real-time with clients, without any client interaction. It uses WebSockets if it's available and falls back to other techniques, such as polling, if a client is using a browser that doesn't implement HTML5 standards.

Comment: I'm looking into that stuff now. The WebSockets issue isn't really an issue since this is mostly just a learning exercise for me right now. I might just go with the WebSocket/SignalR route. The setTimeout option seems like it would be the easiest route, I suppose, but HTML5 stuff wouldn't be a bad thing to learn. Thanks for the help!

Comment: setTimeout is pretty easy but I've seen some people really mess it up too. It's good to know it since you may not always be working with a .NET server or work in an office with tight regulations (i.e., limits what libraries you're allowed to use). But SignalR is a pretty cool library and very cool conceptually